# Is it efficient to create an index with fields that might be missing in some query?

Tags: mysql, mongodb, postgresql, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a product collection with the following fields

- Type
- Country
- State
- City
- Price
- CreatedAt

My queries could be any of the following

```
Product.find({ type, country }).sort({price})

product.find({ type, country }).sort({createdAt})

Product.find({ type, state }).sort({price})

Product.find({ type, state }).sort({createdAt})

Product.find({ type, city }).sort({price})

Product.find({ type, city }).sort({createdAt})
```

For this, I have created the following index. Is this the most efficient index??

```
Product.index({
type: 1,
country: 1,
state: 1,
city: 1,
price: -1,
createdAt: -1,
});
```

Ram is limited. So, I want the indexes to be as few as possible. About 1 million documents are expected to be inserted.

I am using MongoDB but I would also appreciate how it can be done in other databases.

Comment: *how it can be done in other databases.* For MySQL: *My queries could be any of the following* What is the amount (in percent) of calls for each separate query? What is the amount of rows (in percent) selected by each query (in average)? Create one composite index where `type` is a prefix and an additional column which is used in the filtering condition as the most often criteria is the rest. *I have created the following index. Is this the most efficient index?* No. Moreover, in last 4 queries the server won't use it with high probability.

Comment: Optimisation will be different in each different DBMS.

Comment: Do people enter the city name "London" with no country or state because they actually want all the minor Londons in the world, or just because they are lazy?

Comment: I can add that.

Comment: @Akina In MySQL , if the cardinality of columns used in the search condition is too low but the  cardinality of columns used in the ORDER BY clause is very high, should the index for sorting be favoured over the one for searching?

Comment: @blabla_bingo Must be tested. But I doubt.